# How to display the data in table HTML format in Skype Bot Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-bots

I have already done with the example given for Node.js SDK [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2785) but no luck. 
In Skype client it showing text not the table formatting.

```
bot.dialog('message_with_table', function (session) {
    var tableHTML = '<table style="padding:10px;border:1px solid black;"><tr style="background-color:#c6c6c6"><th>Countries</th><th>Capitals</th><th>Population</th><th>Language</th></tr><tr><td>USA</td><td>Washington D.C.</td><td>309 million</td><td>English</td></tr><tr><td>Sweden</td><td>Stockholm</td><td>9 million</td><td>Swedish</td></tr></table>';
    var message = {
        type: 'message',
        textFormat: 'xml', 
        text: tableHTML
    };
    session.send(message);
});
```

I'm not able to understand what is the issue, its working in Bot Framework emulator but not in skype and FB messanger.

I know The [TextFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-create-messages#message-text-and-format) xml is supported only by the Skype channel but it not working in my case.

Comment: You are trying to send html...with textFormat xml...

Comment: I suppose to use the same as comment mention by nwhitmont  Example (Node SDK): here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2785 any suggestion to this.